# How can I cast my local video to chromecast?

Tags: google-chrome, chromecast

I checked out this [example code](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome) for casting videos on tv using Google chromecast. But I can't figure out how can I programmatically cast my local videos. It only works for online hosted videos and when I enter the local URL in "Enter custom media URL" field and click on Load Custom Media, it shows "media error".

I think some work needs to be done with [chrome.cast.media.mediainfo](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo). Can somebody help me out?